# How can I store a function into a variable when my function has user input

Tags: python

I want to store a python function which has an input function [eg: a = input("Item number: ")], into a variable.

So when I call that variable, it should initiate the main function stored in it.

I tried to make a sample function:

1. Which takes input from a user and returns it.
2. Stored that function into a variable, let's say x.

```
    def user_input():
        item_number = input("Item number: ")
        return item_number
    x=user_input()
```

-Now when I'm calling that variable x, it is returning the value which was 
 given to the function as input.

-What I want is, it should initiate the function stored in it and ask the user 
 for input.

Comment: `x = user_input`?

Comment: <function __main__.user_input()> 
This is what it returns.

Comment: Yes, but now you have to call it: `x()`. Although I don't really see the point of *x* in this context.

Comment: I want to call the function just with the help of variable x. This variable x, I'm going to use in html to show the output of x over web.

Comment: There is new feature coming in python3.8 for this same reason, its called "walrus" operator, you can do that by x:= user_input(). it calles user_input() method and stores the returned value into the variable x.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like -

```
def user_input():
    item_number = input("Item number: ")
    return item_number
x=user_input
#when want to call the function 
y = x()
```

Comment: Not working, I just want to call the variable x and it should initiate the function.

Comment: Which version of Python you are working on? Currently the feature you are requesting is not available.. please add a feature request in python

Comment: Python 3.7, is there any other way to do this?